# H2 - Setting variable does not work as expected

Tags: sql, database, h2

I am using h2 to generate some data for tests.
I have a select statement, that selects a random row in a table.

Within the select statement I set a variable called 'K' with the SET function (http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#set).
In a second statement within the same session I try to read / get the current value of the variable.

To get a reproducible result I use SYSTEM_RANGE(1,10) in the select statement below. I use the h2 web console to execute the statements.

If I set the variable like in the following statement

```
SET @K = SELECT X FROM SYSTEM_RANGE(1,10) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

and I execute a subsequent VALUES statement

```
VALUES(@K)
```

it works as expected. The variable K has been set to a random value. Subsequent executions of both these statements show, that value of the variable changes randomly.
I would like to assign the variable within a select statement. Setting the variable as shown above does not help in reaching my goal.

This does not work as expected

```
SELECT SET(@K,X) FROM SYSTEM_RANGE(1,10) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
VALUES(@K); -- value of K is different than result of above select
            -- subsequent executions show that the result of the select changes as expected 
            — but the result of the values statement and thus the value of K does not change
```

I would expect the result of the select statement to be the same as the value of the variable, but they are not. Subsequent executions of both statements show, that the select statements delivers randomly selected results, but the values statement delivers the same / a constant integer.

Answer (score 0):

(I tried a little....) and it is possible (not to call `RAND`, anytime you call `VALUES`):

```
SET @K = FLOOR(RAND() * 9) + 1;
VALUES(@K);
```

"Just omit" the select statement in `SET`

Comment: I am not interested in getting a reproducible result. I just want the assignment to the variable to be permanent, in order to use the randomly selected value in subsequent statements. My goal is to select the first row in the table at random and than I would like to do lookups in other tables with this randomly selected value. This approach garanties random data selection and consistency.